# Filtering rows which are causing datatype parsing issue in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark dataFrame with column Salary as shown below:

```
|Salary|
|"100"|
|"200"|
|"abc"|
```

The dafault datatype is string. I want to convert that to Integer with removing those rows which are causing parsing issue.

**Desired Output**

```
|Salary|
|100|
|200|
```

Can someone please let me know the code for filtering the rows which will be causing datatype parsing issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the desired Field with a regex and then casting the column:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._    

df.filter(row => row.getAs[String]("Salary").matches("""\d+"""))
  .withColumn("Salary", $"Salary".cast(IntegerType))
```

You can do it also with Try if you don't like regex:

```
import scala.util._

df.filter(row => Try(row.getAs[String]("Salary").toInt).isSuccess)
  .withColumn("Salary", $"Salary".cast(IntegerType))
```

Comment: @ankush If the answer has served your purpose, then for the sake of courtesy accept the answer